How to save this patio from sinking?
The image below shows the same patio from above and below. The patio has been sinking. I had removed the bluestone from the top. You can see on the picture on the right that the most recent slab has sunk about 8" (in the last three or four years). So the earth below the concrete must be getting washed out from underneath of the patio and probably finds its way downhill.
I'm confident that one the issues is the lack of appropriate drainage which I intend to fix this time around. I'll pull out all the stops and that should help matters at least a little bit.
But I'm concerned that, as the hill that the patio is on top of moves, the earth will move down too simply due to gravity. So, I'm looking for any advice I can get on anything related to remediating this problem - but I'm mostly wondering if I neeed to be doing something about the hill that the patio is sitting on.


This issue screams for an engineer.  You cannot get any worthwhile information from us internet people.

This is probably bigger than what we can help with online.  You want landscapers/local geologist/foundation/building contractors on site to help.  Neighbourhoods in California are losing their whole homes/streets due to similar problems.

Can't afford an engineer. Either find good advice online or watch the patio slide downhill.

@Wynne, You cannot get good information online.  You need a qualified engineer to come to you home and gather pertinent information.  There may be a geological analysis needed. NONE of this can be done by some unknown typing on a keyboard , or by watching a video of some maybe kinda related patio on a hill stuff.

The only problem with that is today is the patio.  Tomorrow is the house.   This is not a DIY problem.  Maybe your local city/county might have people that can give advice.

Getting an engineer out to look and recommend a fix might not be too expensive maybe $500 if you find an owner operator.
It depends a bit on the geology and what that hill is made of.  You can drill piles down into the slope to add stability.  How far you drill down comes down to the soil types though.  You could take some galvanized fence post and sledge hammer it down into the hillside until it stops going down anymore.  That can only help stabilize it.  You can also do geotextile with tie backs and earth bags.  These have prescriptive guides that tell you how to build.  deltalok is the one I've used.
Deltalok can go up 10' with a 6' horizontal ratio and it is just bags you fill with dirt.

Yeah, the OP has a slope stability problem.  Hard to provide a solution, though, without better pics (not enough context).  But if he can't afford an engineer, IMO he can't afford a solution—OP really needs a retaining wall.

Hard to say with the pictures.  It looks like it just might be the patio slab that settled and that the surrounding wall has stayed the same so it could just be that the fill used under the patio wasn't properly compacted and settled.

Upon closer inspection of the second photo, it doesn't look like the dropoff is that steep—the first one makes it look like there's almost a cliff.  Still, the patio falling 3' is probably as big a problem as it falling 10'.  It does look like there's been some erosion on the slope.  Perhaps some slope stabilization would prevent future subsidence.
